# set player rotation from point A to B in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When moving the player I use this code for the player rotation. The player should always rotate to the target point he will move to.

```
private void SetPlayerRotation(Vector3 targetCellPosition)
{
    Vector3 targetPoint = new Vector3(targetCellPosition.x, transform.position.y, targetCellPosition.z) - transform.position;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint, Vector3.up); // rotate the player
}
```

Sometimes the console logs

> Look rotation viewing vector is zero

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is being logged if vector is zero, making an if statement will fix this. The reason behind logging of this is when rotation vector is 0 nothing happens so doing this task is pointless.

```
if (targetPoint != Vector3.Zero) {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint, Vector3.up);
}
```